# With android xml, suppose I have a table layout with rows of buttons. Is there a way to change the button height of one button to fill two rows?

Tags: android, xml

With android xml, suppose I have a table layout with rows of buttons. Is there a way to change the button height of one button to fill two rows? For example I would like a calculator with the "equals" button on the right being twice as tall like in many simple calculators.

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout only supports column spanning, not row spanning, so in this case you need to nest your table within another layout, and add the equals button in the outer layout.  For example, you could use a horizontal LinearLayout as the outer layout.